# If a user uploads an infected file but my Django server does not write it to disk, is my server still at risk?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

In the Django docs, it mentions that image uploads below 2.5MB are not written to disk, just to memory. I just need my server to process these images. My concern though, is it possible for my server to still get infected despite not writing them to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Assuming there's no stray daemon on your ubuntu box that attempts to interact with the newly written file and get infected because of a security hole, you will still process the image. Image processing libraries get attacked from time to time such as [libexif](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/4996/Libexif-Libexif.html?vendor_id=2861), [ImageMagick](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1749/Imagemagick.html) and [OpenCV](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-16327/Opencv.html), and those libraries don't care that your file comes from memory/disk, since all they see is just stream of bytes. As always, the correct defense is to keep your libraries and framework updated, and limit the user account running the process to reduce the damage if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks Martheen! I may have mispoken though, by processing, I meant it very loosely as I'd be sending it through a messaging API ( https://core.telegram.org/ ) so no libraries. Does that still count?

Comment: The risk become much smaller then, but if your JSON serializer somehow does have a security hole, then yeah, the risk is still exactly the same between holding on memory and storing to disk.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot Martheen.